# Adding items not incrementing rather it combines the numbers

Tags: node.js, express

I have the lines of code below to sum the Customer balance and the next deposit. Instead of adding, it combines the numbers. Example.

First operation balance is 0 and amount is 50. Then

```
0 + 50 = 50
```

Second operation balance is 50 and say amount is 100

```
50 + 100 = 50100 // instead of 150
```

I will appreciate your help

Code

```
exports.deposit = (req, res) => {
    const {amount, cardId} = req.body 
    
    const card = Card.findOne({user: req.profile._id, _id: cardId})
        .exec((error, card) => {
            if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
            if(card){
                card.balance = card.balance + amount
            }

            card.save((error, card) => {
                if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
                if(card){
                    return res.status(201).json({ card});
                }
            });
        })
};
```

Comment: They might be a string instead of a number - Try `Number(card.balance) + Number(amount)`

Comment: Or have them casted directly to numbers if you can, way better

Comment: It "card" JSON data? If yes, you might try "let cardData = JSON.parse(card)" before perform further processing to avoid casting all of the data by yourself.